# tempfile.TemporaryDirectory contextmanager does not use /tmp folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, python-3.6, redhat

I use the `tempfile.TemporaryDirectory` class as a contextmanager. It should use the `/tmp` folder in default. I have tried to use the default value and also tried to force to use the `/tmp` folder. It creates the temp folder to where the caller script is.

**Set-up:**

- Red Hat 7 Linux
- Python 3.6.6
- The script is called from Jenkins

**Code:**

```
import tempfile
import os

print(os.path.dirname(__file__))
TMP_DIR_PREFIX = "my_test_"
with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory(prefix=TMP_DIR_PREFIX, dir="/tmp") as tmp_dir:
       print(tmp_dir)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 /home/my_home/test.py 
home/my_home
home/my_home/my_test_m1vljq2h
```

**My questions:**

- Does anybody have any idea how I can solve it?
- How is it possible? I have checked the implementation of the `TemporaryDirectory` class but I couldn't see any reasons. I would be very happy if somebody would be able to explain the reason of it.

I have already read the related official documentation as well as the implementation of `tempfile` module but I didn't find any related code part which can cause this type of issue.

**NOTE:** If it is possible I don't want to inherit and change many elements of this module but I am open for ideas.

**EDIT:**

**Complete traceback (From Jenkins running):**

```
File "/my_path/python/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/my_path/python/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/my_home/copy_to_location.py", line 143, in upload_files
    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory(prefix=TMP_DIR_PREFIX, dir="/tmp") as tmp_dir:
  File "/my_path/python/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/tempfile.py", line 790, in __init__
    self.name = mkdtemp(suffix, prefix, dir)
  File "/my_path/python/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/tempfile.py", line 368, in mkdtemp
    _os.mkdir(file, 0o700)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/my_home/my_test_q1pldmf2'
```

**EDIT2:**

I am not able to reproduce it in local. This issue happens only in Jenkins constantly!

**EDIT3:**

Added line:

```
logging.info(tempfile._sanitize_params("my_test_", None, None))
```

Output in Jenkins:

```
2019-11-08 15:09:26 [Thread-1] [INFO] ('my_test_', '', '/tmp', <class 'str'>)
```

Changed line:

```
logging.info(tempfile._sanitize_params("my_test_", None, "/tmp"))
```

Added in Jenkins:

```
2019-11-08 15:13:46 [Thread-1] [INFO] ('my_test_', '', '/tmp', <class 'str'>)
```

Comment: I also get `/tmp/my_test_<random characters>`  - Linux Mint 19.2

Comment: I have added the complete traceback, I think it can be helpful.

Comment: If I don't provide the `dir` parameter, I get the same result. I don't understand, how it is possible...

Comment: Your traceback doesn't show us what `TMP_DIR_PREFIX` is set to. Are you certain that that value if hard-coded like this, or could it be that the value of that prefix has changed?

Comment: The `TMP_DIR_PREFIX` is a constant and it doesn't change.

Comment: What is the value of `TMPDIR` environmental variable?

Comment: @jww: that doesn't matter here, when `dir` is passed in.

Comment: @milanbalazs: **VERIFY** that assumption. I strongly suspect it is not as constant as you think it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()` object uses [`tempfile.mkdtemp()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.mkdtemp) to create the temporary directory from the arguments passed in. This, in turn, will use [`tempfile.gettempdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.gettempdir) if you don't give it a `dir` argument.

If you are passing in a `dir='/tmp'` and *still* don't see the directory created in `/tmp`, then there are two possibilities:

- your `prefix` value is not what you think it is, but rather starts with a `/`
- the `tempfile` module *on your system* has been altered and is no longer behaving the same way as the [standard library version distributed with Python 3.6.0](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.0/Lib/tempfile.py). The changes could have been made on disk, or by other Python code that changed the behaviour dynamically.

The normal behaviour is for the `mkdtemp()` function to call an internal function named [`_sanitize_params()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.0/Lib/tempfile.py#L118-L133), which returns `dir` unchanged if it is set, and the value of `gettempdir()` otherwise:

```
>>> import tempfile
>>> tempfile._sanitize_params('my_test_', None, '/tmp')
('my_test_', '', '/tmp', <class 'str'>)
>>> tempfile._sanitize_params('my_test_', None, None)
('my_test_', '', '/tmp', <class 'str'>)
>>> tempfile.gettempdir()
'/tmp'
```

`mkdtemp()` then uses the results of that call (returning updated `prefix`, `suffix`, `dir` and either the `bytes` or `str` type) together with random strings, to create a new directory for you.

This leads to the possibility is that you haven't ruled out, properly, that the `prefix` value is indeed what you think it is. The `mkdtemp()` function uses:

```
os.path.join(dir, prefix + name + suffix)
```

to join the `dir` path with the concatenation of your prefix, the candidate `name` (random value) and the suffix (empty string in your case). But note that the [`os.path.join()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) will **discard any path elements that come before an argument that starts with a `/` slash**:

```
>>> import os.path
>>> os.path.join("/foo", "bar")
'/foo/bar'
>>> os.path.join("/foo", "/bar")
'/bar'
```

So the behaviour you see could also be explained by your prefix starting with a slash, so:

```
TMP_DIR_PREFIX = "/home/my_home/my_test_"
```

would immediately produce the same result:

```
>>> TMP_DIR_PREFIX = "/home/my_home/my_test_"
>>> tempfile.mkdtemp(prefix=TMP_DIR_PREFIX, dir="/tmp")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/.../lib/python3.6/tempfile.py", line 368, in mkdtemp
    _os.mkdir(file, 0o700)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/my_home/my_test_v4cqpamm'
```

This was reported previously to the Python project as [issue #35278](https://bugs.python.org/issue35278).

You can trivially include two tests in your Jenkins job to rule out these options. Make sure you log the `TMP_DIR_PREFIX` value, as well as what `tempfile._sanitize_params(TMP_DIR_PREFIX, None, '/tmp')` returns.

If either doesn't produce the expected output on your system, then you know you need to focus on looking for; either the `tempfile` module behaviour has changed, or your assumption that `TMP_DIR_PREFIX` has the value that it does is incorrect.

You can check if the local copy differs from the publish version with the following shell command:

```sh
$ diff -u \
> <(curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python/cpython/v3.6.0/Lib/tempfile.py) \
> /my_path/python/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/tempfile.py
```

or you could calculate a checksum for the file:

```
import hashlib
with open(tempfile.__file__, 'rb') as file_to_hash:
    tempfile_checksum = hashlib.sha1(file_to_hash.read()).hexdigest()
```

and compare that checksum value with the one for the published file:

```
$ curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python/cpython/v3.6.0/Lib/tempfile.py | \
> sha1sum
38ad01ccc5972e193e1b96a1de8b7ba1bd8d289d  -
```

If that doesn't turn up anything, you'll either have step through the calls with a debugger or look at the `__module__` attributes of the functions involved. E.g. if `_sanitize_params()` was dynamically altered (*monkey patched*) then `tempfile._sanitize_params.__module__` will not be set to `'tempfile'`, for example. However, note that your traceback already shows that both `TemporaryDirectory.__init__` and `mkdtemp` are taken from the correct file and that the line numbers for the two lines visible match those in the published source.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer, it is so useful to understand the behavior for me. I am working on to check the return value of `_sanitize_params` function. Just I need to test it in the Jenkins because as I mentioned in my question (EDIT2) this issue is reproducible only in Jenkins.

Comment: @milanbalazs: yes, I've seen that, and have further questions for you there.

Comment: @milanbalazs: I've re-ordered my answer a little, because I am more and more convinced that this is caused by the `TMP_DIR_PREFIX` value differing from your assumed value.

Comment: But the prefix mechanism is working fine because the name of directory contains the provided prefix. I don't think that it is the problem. Somehow, the path is not correct... But this issue is getting more and more strange for me...

Comment: @milanbalazs: I **show in my answer** how I can reproduce the exact same problem. `TMP_DIR_PREFIX` only *ends* in `my_test_`, so yes, the end result contains `my_test_`, but it is the **rest** of the `TMP_DIR_PREFIX` value that causes the issue.

Comment: @milanbalazs: you could trivially test this by not using `TMP_DIR_PREFIX` and instead using `prefix="my_test_"` in your code.

Comment: @milanbalazs: the fact that `tempdir._sanitize_params()` produces the expected output leaves only two options: `tempdir.py` has been altered on disk on the system that runs the Jenkins worker *or* your `prefix` value is set to `/home/my_home/my_test_`. I think it is much more likely to be the latter.

Comment: ♦: A really big thank for you! Briefly, many Python scripts in a quite big complex system use this Python module to upload files to a FTP server. I have cross-checked many scripts which use this module based on your analysis and I managed to find the error! I will explain it in my next comment.

Comment: A script sets the `TMP_DIR_PREFIX` constant to `__file__.replace(".py", "_")` and it is okay if you call the script directly (from the same folder) but if you call other place then the `__file__` variable contains the complete relative path and the prefix of temp dir also will contain it. And as you mentioned if the prefix contains a valid path the dir parameter doesn't matter. I am not sure it is a bug in `tempfile` module or not. It is strange that the `tempfile` module uses the prefix as a valid path to temp folder...

Comment: @milanbalazs: you could argue that the module should defend against the `prefix` starting with a slash, yes. I'll see about filing a bug report

Comment: @milanbalazs: in fact, it has [already been reported](https://bugs.python.org/issue35278).